# How do I convert an app engine WAR folder into a single WAR file

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, tomcat

Currently I have created a web application and have it deployed via GAE(Google App Engine). It currently creates a WAR Folder. I need to be able to convert this project to be deployed on tomcat.

Is there anyway that I can convert the WAR folder into a single WAR file, or does anyone know how to convert an app engine project in eclipse to work with tomcat.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have created a project using the Google App Engine plugin for Eclipse. That project structure looks very similar to the Eclipse Dynamic Web project structure, the only difference is the war folder which is an Eclipse project is probably called WebContent.

First you need to add the **Dynamic Web Module** facet to the project. Right click on the project and select Properties, on the properties window choose Project Facets and check the Dynamic Web Module option, click Apply then Ok

[image]

At this stage Eclipse will change the icon of the project and create a WebContent folder, now delete this folder and tell Eclipse to use the war folder instead. Again right click on the project and select Deployment Assembly then remove the WebContent folder and add the war folder.

[image]

Finally export the project as a war file, select the project form the File menu select Export, then choose Web --> War File, enter destination file, etc...

[image]

**Note:** I've not tried this myself so not sure if your war will run under Tomcat or not

Comment: It does work to create a single war file, however it doesn't run on tomcat. If anyone has any other ideas, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just that it can't be deployed, the war file doesn't deploy properly on tomcat

Comment: I've tried the above steps on a vanilla App Engine project created in Eclipse. I'm able to deploy and run the project on Tomcat installed in Eclipse. I'm also able to run the war in standalone Tomcat! May be worth unzipping your war and checking if everything is in the right location. One thing, when exporting it to a war file I check the box that says 'Optimize for a specific runtime' and chosen my Tomcat server installed in Eclipse